# Xmlstarlet or Xmllint - how to save validation errors to a file

Tags: xml, validation

Both Xmlstarlet or Xmllint have a validation what helps to check errors in an XML file

```
xmlstarlet val test.xml
```

or

```
xmllint --valid test.xml
```

gives something similar like

```
/test.xml:5045: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: item line 5042 and description
well as HTML 5 tour supported.Multilingual tour supported.Man more.</description
                                                                               ^
/test.xml:6388: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: item line 6385 and description
 <em>**</em></description>
                          ^
```

But how to save this long list of errors to a usual TXT file ?
No any normal outputs like

```
xmllint --valid test.xml > /errors/error_test.txt
```

does not work.
Thanks in advance for any hint to try !

Comment: Maybe they use stderr and not stdout. Search for capture stderr to file in DOS and test that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin hint above a solution was found.
Use

```
xmllint --valid test.xml 2>&1 | more > /errors/error_test.txt
```